# CFStringRef from char* without providing encoding type

Tags: ios, utf-8, utf-16, cfstring, nsstringencoding

I have a C string:

```
unsigned char* contents = readInFile(path); //sting bytes in some unknown NSStringEncoding encoding.
```

I want to know the current `NSStringEncoding` value of contents. I want to do this without using `NSString usedEncoding` methods.

I need a `CFStringRef` from contents without introducting a new string encoding.

```
NSString* contentsString = [NSString stringWithCString:(char *)contents];
```

introduces default encoding so screws things up. How can a create a `CFStringRef` dirctly from contents?

Once I have this I can:

```
CFStringEncoding cfStringEncoding = CFStringGetFastestEncoding((CFStringRef)contentsString);
NSStringEncoding encoding = CFStringConvertEncodingToNSStringEncoding(cfStringEncoding);
```

Comment: Can you read in the file as an NSData object, then use CFStringCreateWithBytes(), specifying UTF8 as the encoding? If there is a marker prefix in the data, that method probably ignores your suggestion of UTF8 and uses it instead.

Comment: You can't read file into a string unless you know its encoding. Usually in this case ISO-8859-1 is used (or fragile charset detection heuristics but that's complicated), because it turns every byte into a character that maps to a Unicode code point directly from the byte's value.